# Desktop Infrastructure - My Windows 7 Loads the incorrect profile

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I have Windows 7 Professional 64Bit installed, at start up when I enter my username and password it loads as per normal, but i could not see any of my programs installed or find any of my files, after digging around in the C drive i found the user folder and i could see three profiles my profile, public and temp, my files are all in my profile folder, but when i log in (using my usual profile) it seems to direct me to the Temp Folder. Has anyone come accross this and can you please help me to fix this?

Comment: Is the machine a member of an AD domain? Are you logging in with a domain account or a local account? Is there anything in the event viewer related to failed profile loads? Server Fault is for **professional** systems administrators. We assume that you've done a minimal level of troubleshooting and log gathering before you ask a question here.

Comment: Hi MDMarra - Thank you for the quick response, this is on a local account and the eventviewer shows nothing related to failed profiles, i have tried everyhting i know of but have not come to an answer.

Comment: @MarceOlivier Please share what have you tryied. This will help us form an anwser.

Comment: Windows thinks your existing profile is corrupt for some reason. This could be many things, security issues, corrupted ntuser.dat, registry problems. "I have tried everything I know" does not help us. **Be specific**.

Comment: @ChrisS after troubleshooting, i also came to the same conclusion that windows thinks the profile is corrupt, but i couldnt find anything wrong with the profile itself,only with the association of windows associating the wrong profile with the wrong user name,which leads me to believe the registry is not directing the right username to the right profile, my big question now is, and sorry for not wording it clearly on the day i posted the first time,how do i fix this or is it even fixable?

Comment: The Event Log will have an entry every time you try to login with "Windows cannot logon you because the profile cannot be loaded" plus more information. Check it out and it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you Chris S, youre information was of great value.